# Trasponer una lista, pero no se copia línea por línea

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero trasponer una la lista `aux`, pero en cada paso se copia más de una vez.

```
aux=[["a"]*len(cadena)]*len(cadena[0])
for i in range(len(aux)):
   for j in range(len(aux[i])):
       aux[i][j] = cadena[j][i]
       print (i,j,aux[i][j],cadena[j][i])
       print(aux)
print (aux)
```

Answer (score 4):

Solo para ampliar un poco las opciones, si lo que deseas es transponer una matriz hay otras formas además de los ciclos for anidados 'tradicionales', partiendo de una matriz, por ejemplo:

```
matriz = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

- Compresión de listas:

  ```
  aux = [[fila[i] for fila in matriz ] for i in range(len(matriz[0]))]
  ```
- Usar `zip` sobre la lista desempaquetada (`*`):

  ```
  aux = [list(f) for f in (zip(*matriz))]
  ```
- También se puede usar `map` en vez de la sintaxis de compresión de listas anterior pero creo que es más confuso:

  ```
  aux = list(map(list, zip(*matriz)))
  ```
- Si tienes que tratar con casos en el que hay listas anidadas con diferentes longitudes (no en caso de matrices que se supone que esto no pasa) puedes usar [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), en este caso se rellena los espacios con ceros:

  ```
  from itertools import zip_longest
  aux = [list(f) for f in zip_longest(*matriz, fillvalue = 0)]
  ```

En todos los casos `aux` es:

> [[0, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5]]

- Y por supuesto, si vas a tratar con matrices y te lo permiten usa [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/) sin dudarlo, facilita mucho la vida y es más eficiente:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  aux = np.array(matriz).T
  ```

Y obtenemos:

> array([[0, 2, 4],
>      [1, 3, 5]])

Answer (score 2):

Va contra el Zen de python, pero para fines ilustrativos listo algunas maneras (ver la respuesta de FJSevilla). La forma idiomatica es *list comprehension.*

**Opción 1:** usar una lista temporal

```
def trans(matriz):
    '''
    Encuentra la transpuesta de un matriz
    assumiendo hileras de la misma longitud
    '''
    hileras = len (matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    t = [[0 for x in range(hileras)] for y in range(columnas)] 

    for i in range(hileras):
        for j in range(columnas):
            t[j][i] = matriz[i][j]
    return t
aux =[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]]
aux = trans(aux)
```

**Opción 2:** usar la libreria numpy

```
 import numpy as np
 dos = np.transpose(aux)
```

**Opción 3:** usar la función zip

```
 tres = [list(i) for i in zip(*aux)]
```

**Opción 4:** usar *list comprehension*

```
cuatro = [[hilera [i] for hilera in aux] for i in range (len (aux [0]))]
```

**Opción 5:** usar *itertools*

```
from itertools import zip_longest
cinco = [list (columna) for columna in zip_longest (*aux, fillvalue = 0)]
```

Comment: Para hacer lo que hace esa función, puedes usar la funcion `zip` de python, con la cual te ahorras escribir el código, y será una forma más optimizada

Comment: Gracias por la observación